# SQL Insert with Select and Parameter

Tags: sql, select, insert, sqlparameter

Hello I have a problem

```
declare @target_date datetime
set @target_date=GETDATE();


insert into table1 ([column1],[column2],[column3])
(select [column1],[column2] from table2 where id=@id), @target_date
```

How can I solve this problem

**Insert**
Table1.Column1=Table2.Column1
Table1.Column2=Table2.Column2
Table1.Column3=@target_date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare @target_date datetime
set @target_date=GETDATE();


insert into table1 ([column1],[column2],[column3])
select [column1],[column2], @target_date from table2 where id=@id
```

Just make the variable the value of a calculated column

Answer (score 0):

you don't need () for select command after insert, and you have to move @target_date inside the select command.

Comment: Technically you would be correct, though I have already answered that way.  It would be good in the future to show the actual change via code rather than a straight narrative it is easier for others to follow your answer that way.